# How do I set my Jasper Report JDBC URL relative to the location of the application?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, jasper-reports

I want to connect to my database, but the location of the database is the same folder (dist) as the JAR file. That folder will not always be in the same location on every computer, and I have my program set up to be accessible over a network. (That's why I put the database in the same folder as the JAR file to begin with.)

I just need to know how to connect to my database by a URL that is relative to the database's location. I can't use `jdbc:h2:./GiftCertificateManagerDatabase;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE` because it thinks that I'm searching for the database in "C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0". How do I fix this problem?

As always, thank you in advance for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java to find out your current working directory, there's plenty of examples online:

```
return new File("").getAbsoluteFile();
```

for instance.
The case in which you get "C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0" is specific to when you are developing under Netbeans and running the project from there, you can set a flag to use while in "development mode" which searches for a fixed development database folder.